# На фрейме не отображаются графические эллементы

Tags: java, netbeans

Вообщем на фрейме не отображаются графические элементы, они создаются я могу на них навести курсором и курсор как описано в программе изменяется на крестик, но фрейм как будто застелен серой пеленной...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MoveCircle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Перемещение круга");
      MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.show();
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MyFrame(){
        setTitle("Поле");
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.add(panel);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList circle;
    private Ellipse2D current;

    public MyPanel(){
        circle = new ArrayList();
        current = null;
        addMouseListener (new MyMouse());
        addMouseMotionListener(new myMove());
    }

    public void paintCompnent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2.setBackground(Color.white);    
       for (int i=0;i<circle.size();i++) {
            g2.setColor(new Color ((i*200+20)%255,(i*80+10)%255,(i*100+50)%255));
            g2.fill((Ellipse2D)circle.get(i));
       }
    }

    public void add(Point p){
       current = new Ellipse2D.Double(p.getX()-10,p.getY()-10,20,20);
       circle.add(current);
       repaint();
    }

    public Ellipse2D find(Point2D p){
       for(int i=0;i<circle.size();i++)
       {
          Ellipse2D e=(Ellipse2D) circle.get(i);
          if(e.contains(p)) return e;
       }
       return null;
    }

    public void remove(Ellipse2D e){
       if(e==null) return;
       if(e==current) current=null;
       circle.remove(e);
       repaint();
    }

private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
        current = find(event.getPoint());
        if (current == null) 
           add(event.getPoint());
    }

    public void mouseClicled(MouseEvent event){
        if (event.getClickCount()>=2){
            current = find(event.getPoint());
            if (current != null) 
               remove (current);
            }        
        }
    }

    private class myMove implements MouseMotionListener{
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){
            if(find(event.getPoint())==null)
                setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
            else
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor
                     (Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
        }   

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
            if(current!=null){
                current.setFrame(event.getX()-10,event.getY()-10,20,20);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяй `paintCompnent()` в `MyPanel` на `paintComponent()` (у тебя пропущено «o»).

И еще, когда работаешь в гуи, то использовать `System.out.println()`, то есть давать взаимодействовать консольке и окнам, просто некорректно.

Comment: Добавлю: чтобы подобных ошибок не происходило, надо использовать аннотацию `@override`.